# _f_data_rom linker script symbols

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, codewarrior

I am working  on startup code of micro controller 32 bit and `codewarrior` compiler , As we have to deal with linker script. Certain variables that used in startup code for initilization of `RAM` and `stack` come from linker script.

Linker Script initialize these  variables with different address. Problem is one variable have wrong address. In linker script it initialized by following command  `_f_data_rom`.

- Could any one tell me how linker initiazed variables that provides
  address for stack , RAM initialization?
- What this command means `_f_data_rom` ?

it looks like

```
RC_SDATA_SRC       = _f_sdata_rom;
RC_SDATA_DEST      = _f_sdata;
RC_SDATA_SIZE      = (SIZEOF(.sdata)+3) / 4;
RC_DATA_SRC        = _f_data_rom;
RC_DATA_DEST       = _f_data;
RC_DATA_SIZE       = (SIZEOF(.data)+3) / 4;
```

Comment: You should post the whole linker script. BTW I guess it is the address of static data location in flash. Usually are defined as a section somewhere in flash address space.

Comment: Those variable seems to be source (flash) and dest (ram) addresses to perform copy of values of bss section allocated variables at boot time (e.g. start.s)

Comment: Yes, you are right it is doing the same job. But the problem is  ''_f_data_rom'' is fetching wrong address of  flash.

So I am worried, how this commad  ''_f_data_rom'' works? How can I fix that it fetch the correct address of flash.

Comment: Those values are automatically calculated based on project settings I guess. Take a look at page 65 as reported in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [this document](http://www.nxp.com/files/soft_dev_tools/doc/user_guide/MOBILEGTUG.pdf) at page 69 you have to look at `__ppc_eabi_linker.h` how those variable are exported, e.g: [this link to file](http://read.pudn.com/downloads62/sourcecode/embed/216891/__ppc_eabi_linker.h__.htm)

Into the same document, at page 65 you can find the form that configure addresses for linker. Take a look at that and check those settings.